# Algorithm in O(logn)

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

I have a project where I should write the following algorithm :

> Let an integer function $f\colon\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be monotone and suppose that $f(1) > 0$ and $f(n) < 0$. We would like to find the smallest integer $i$ with $f(i) < 0$. Design an algorithm for this purpose that run in time $O(\log n)4.

I tried to search in the middle ($\frac{n+1}2$) and then go in the right half or in the left half (like binary search) but the input is not sorted. Could someone give me an idea of how I can continue?

Comment: "but the input is not sorted" -- why? It's always important to check one's assumptions.

Comment: With a monotone function, you would be right. But if you are lucky and the function is monotonic, then the values of the function are indeed sorted. Because that's what monotonic means ("monotone" means unchanging in pitch. )

Answer (score 3):

This can be viewed as an array with indices given by $1,2,3,\dots,n$ such that $f(i)$ is stored at index $i$.

As $f(i)$ is monotonic, and the sign changes from positive to negative with increasing $i$, it can be concluded that $f(i)$ is a decreasing function, which tells us that the array is sorted in decreasing order.

Here, we are looking for the smallest index $i$ such that $f(i)\lt 0$. We need to find a particular value of $i$ such that $f(i-1)\ge 0$ and $f(i)\lt 0$. Such an $i$ must be unique because for all indices greater than $i$, $f$ must be negative and for all indices less than $i-1$, $f$ must be non negative. Such an $i$ must exist as it is given that for at least one value each, $f$ takes positive and negative values. The index $i$ can be found by binary search as you suggested.